# How do I rotate multiple objects individually in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, smartobject

I have a horizontal row of many different smart objects of the same size. 
I made the row vertical by selecting all the objects and using the free transform tool to rotate the whole row 90 degrees.

Now I got the problem that all the objects are facing the wrong way at 90 degrees.
I can of course select and rotate them individually, but that takes a lot of time.

So to my question, is there a way to rotate multiple objects individually?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the objects spaced evenly? Then you can avoid the problem altogether by taking a different approach. Move the top and bottom objects to where you want them to be, and roughly position the rest in between, in order. Then use the alignment buttons to align them and space them evenly.

Comment: That of course is an option too, but when I use the distribute function they jump all over the place.

Comment: distribution tools are hard to master, I concur. Try to get a feel for them using just simple shapes in a test document.

Comment: I don't know either, but I think that you could just have the letters in different corners. This only works if you use four letter words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a script like this one [Transform Each Beta (Script)](http://blog.kam88.com/en/transform-each-beta-script.html)

Comment: Your answer may be correct but we try to steer clear of just posting links.  Do you mind posting some information on why your link answers the OP's question?  This will help someone in the future if your link ever goes down.